# what will be the efficient way of knowing that only integer data is present in a list in python 3

Tags: python, list

I am trying to achieve a way of checking if the elements of a list are integers or not and after that, I want to throw an assertion error if they are not.

One way I found is to iterate over the list and check for each element data-type. But is there any efficient approach out there to test the same?

I am trying to achieve something like this,

```
def add_edge(self, edge):
   assert len(edge) != 2, "edge list length not equal to 2, enter a list of length 2"
   assert is_any_element_non_int, "expected data type to be int, but found another"
```

Comment: `assert all(isinstance(i, int) for i in edge)`

Comment: The name `edge` implies you want it to the a list with *exactly* two elements, not a list with fewer or more than two.

Comment: @deceze thanks, solved my problem!

Comment: @chepner true!, but I have a requirement in another function where I will need this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stay with generator is recommended in terms of efficiency:

```
a = [1,2,3] 
b = ["1", 2]
print(all(isinstance(item, int) for item in a)) # True
print(all(isinstance(item, int) for item in b)) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

```
if all(isinstance(x,int) for x in myList) == True:
  # YEAH TRUE
else:
  # ALAS EXCEPTION throw error
```